# Android ListView Some Questions

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have some questions about `ListView`. The Post that I've searched doesn't satisfy me.

1. If I have five list items and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in 
   `customAdapter`, How many times does `getView` method called?
2. I have a checkbox on each list and it must be shown only when the delete button is clicked. The Delete button is created on the Activity Class, and the checkbox is created in the Adapter Class (I mean `findViewById`). Then how can I handle this? 
   Currently my code changes flag value on Activity Class  and call 
   notifyDataSetChanged() method on Adapter Class.
3. How can I handle UI without call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method?
   (I've implemented in this way...)

Sorry about not posting my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get view calls every time when item appears at the screen, so in your case it is 5 times.
2. You can do something like that:

   2.1 Create a public method in your adapter, for example:

   ```
   public void setIsDeleteModeEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
       //Logic here
   }
   ```

   2.2 In your `Activity`, when `Button` is clicked call `adapter.setDeleteModeEnabled(true);`

3 You should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` only when dataset is changed. For handling UI events you should:

**In list item**: you should set onClickListeners in `getView()`;

**In `Activity`** : `onCreate()` method in adapter and call it in `Activity`'s onClicks

Comment: Thanks for your response!! If I suppose that, on my screen, there are three list items. Then topmost list item's convertview might be a null at the beginning. What about second and third listview?

Comment: @NaJunYeop sorry I don't understand what are you want. Refrase please

Comment: It's about ViewHolder maybe. I want to save checkbox's check state. But after scrolling, that state changed.

Comment: @NaJunYeop you can save states to Boolean ArrayList (change value in check box onChekedChanded and restore it in getView())

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. Now all I have to do is just trying. Have a nice day!